# Getting 502 server status using nginx and hhvm

Tags: nginx, hhvm

sometimes I get this error message on my website: **502 bad gateway**. After I executed the pkill hhvm command its working. My question is why i get this status and how do i fix it ?
I read this article: https://www.scalescale.com/tips/nginx/502-bad-gateway-using-nginx/ and the first step is to increase the buffer using this code:

```
http {
...
fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
fastcgi_read_timeout 300;
...
}
```

Another question is where should i include this code ? thx

Comment: Have you had a look at nginx and hhvm error logs?

Comment: Yes , I looked over the error logs. It showed me a lot of 502 statuses. Also which url was accessed, the ip, request time etc ... but nothing more specific

Comment: and in the hhvm showed me some php syntax error bugs. But I don;t believe that should cause 502 server error

Comment: Please post the php errors that have occured.

Comment: here is one of them: 
\nFatal error: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting $end in /mypath/to/myfile.php on line 70